# Why doesn't this button go to the bottom left corner tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a page for my tkinter GUI and when I try to put a button to go to the previous page at the bottom left corner it never seems to work.

I have created a frame to put inside the window, packing it to the left side, then packing the button in that frame to the bottom of it.  I have also tried it the other way round, so frame at the bottom and the button on the left.  Changing the values of the size of the frame seems to do nothing.

```py
previousPageF = tk.Frame(self, height = "100", width = "500")
previousPageF.pack(side = "bottom")

previousPageB = tk.Button(previousPageF, font = BASIC_FONT, text = "<--", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
previousPageB.pack(side = "left")
```

[Picture of the results of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b7aG.png)

I want it to be the very bottom left corner and not in the position it is currently in.  I would like to use pack as it is not a very complicated GUI design and pack also puts it automatically in the centre of the window, whereas with grid I would have to do some maths to get it perfectly in the centre.  Furthermore, I have done all of my other work with pack so I would prefer not to change all of it just to get this to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out with trial and error.

```
 previousPageB = tk.Button(self, font = BASIC_FONT, text = "<--", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
 previousPageB.pack(anchor = "w", side = "bottom")
```

This will result in the button being in the bottom left corner:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAI9J.png)

It will also work if you do:

```
previousPageB = tk.Button(self, font = BASIC_FONT, text = "<--", command = lambda: controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
previousPageB.pack(anchor = "s", side = "left")
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use frame for this.You can directly mention fill='none' and side='left' in pack to place widget to left in window.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
previousPageB = tk.Button(root, text = "<--", command = lambda: 
controller.show_frame(LoginPage))
previousPageB.pack(fill='none',side = "left")
```

Comment: How do I make it go to the bottom left corner?  I can do the left side and the bottom but not both combined.  Edit; don't worry I figured it out by using anchor = "w", side = "bottom"